# Implement Clear button for canvas in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, angular9

I'm trying to clear the canvas on button click in angular 9. But on click is shows **ctx.clearcanvas is not a function**. Cannot implement click button to clear the canvas.

Error in my console : **ERROR TypeError: ctx.clearCanvas is not a function
at DrawOnImageComponent_Template_button_click_6_listener**
My angular 9 code is as below :

```js
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-draw-on-image',
  templateUrl: './draw-on-image.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./draw-on-image.component.scss']
})

export class DrawOnImageComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('canvas', {static: false}) canvas: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 60;
    canvas.height = 400;
 
    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.fillRect(0,0 , canvas.width, canvas.height);

    let start_background_color = "white";
    let draw_color = start_background_color;
    let draw_width = 2;
    let is_drawing = false;

    function change_color(element){
      draw_color = element.style.background;
    }

    canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", start, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", start, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw, false);

    canvas.addEventListener("touchend", stop, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stop, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", stop, false);

    function start(event){
      is_drawing = true;
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
                     event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    
    function draw(event){
      if(is_drawing == true){
        context.lineTo(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
                       event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
        event.strokeStyle = draw_color;
        context.lineWidth = draw_width;
        context.lineCap = "round";
        context.lineJoin = "round";
        context.stroke();
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    function stop(event){
      if(is_drawing){
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
        is_drawing = false;
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    function clearCanvas(){
      let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('canvas');
      let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      context.fillStyle = start_background_color;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width,canvas.height);
      context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width,canvas.height);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="field">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <div class="tools">
      <button type="button" class="button">Undo</button>
      <button type="submit" (click)="clearCanvas()">Clear</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Please help me in solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem is the scope of your `clearCanvas()` method. To call it from the template with `(click)="clearCanvas()"` it needs to be declared on your component.

I've made a slight change and commented out some stuff that you'll have to refactor a little bit. this should get you moving:

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('canvas') canvas: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 60;
    canvas.height = 400;
 
    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.fillRect(0,0 , canvas.width, canvas.height);

    let start_background_color = "white";
    let draw_color = start_background_color;
    let draw_width = 2;
    let is_drawing = false;

    function change_color(element){
      draw_color = element.style.background;
    }

    canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", start, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", start, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw, false);

    canvas.addEventListener("touchend", stop, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stop, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", stop, false);

    function start(event){
      is_drawing = true;
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
                     event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    
    function draw(event){
      if(is_drawing == true){
        context.lineTo(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
                       event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
        event.strokeStyle = draw_color;
        context.lineWidth = draw_width;
        context.lineCap = "round";
        context.lineJoin = "round";
        context.stroke();
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    function stop(event){
      if(is_drawing){
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
        is_drawing = false;
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
    clearCanvas(){
      let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('canvas');
      let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      //context.fillStyle = start_background_color; // start_background_color is out of scope here
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width,canvas.height);
      context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width,canvas.height);
    }
  }
```